# How to set up Nodemailer with Angular 4?

Tags: node.js, angular, nodemailer

I can't find a tutorial anywhere that guides me through the process of setting up nodemailer in Angular 4. I'm not even sure in which file to put the ts from the nodemailer intro on their website:

```
'use strict';
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// Generate test SMTP service account from ethereal.email
// Only needed if you don't have a real mail account for testing
nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {

    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
        port: 587,
        secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: account.user, // generated ethereal user
            pass: account.pass  // generated ethereal password
        }
    });

    // setup email data with unicode symbols
    let mailOptions = {
        from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@blurdybloop.com>', // sender address
        to: 'bar@blurdybloop.com, baz@blurdybloop.com', // list of receivers
        subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
        text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
        html: '<b>Hello world?</b>' // html body
    };

    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
        // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
        console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

        // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@blurdybloop.com>
        // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
    });
});
```

This is a complicated thing and any help would be appreciated! If I knew where to put the code and what it should do, I would be able to piece some things together.

Comment: As far as I know `Angular` is a front-end framework. `Nodemailer` is not supposed to run in browser. It needs to be integrated on the server/API if you are using one.

Comment: I'm using npm? Which files do I need to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing client side with server side code.  NodeMailer is a server side package for express.  Angular 4 would call an API to executed that code.
If you want to to get nodemailer up and running, you need to do so within node.
Are you using a back-end such as express?

Comment: I'm not - I'm building a web-app with Angular 4 in the angular-cli and teaching myself as I go. I've built web pages before but nothing so complex.

Comment: I wasn't trying to insult you.  I am just explaining that nodemailer isn't something you run within Angular 4.  It is something you would run on the server side in node.

Comment: Oh no of course not! I think I can be a bit short but I don't mean to be rude! + I didn't think you were either!

Comment: I'm wondering how this affects my hosting? So far I've been able to upload my dist folder to ordinary web hosting - will express change that?

Comment: you can certainly combine express and angular together..
A good starting point is this:
https://github.com/vladotesanovic/angular2-express-starter

Feel free to post new questions or hit me up directly if I can help.  With respect to this open question, I think the issue is as I said, which is that you can't do nodemailer in Angular 4.

Comment: as a side note, as of writing, angular cli installs nodemailer, for what reason is unknown, maybe there is a configuration for ng serve?